# Nav bar with position: fixed not displaying properly?

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="../css/example.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <title>My Portfolio</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="nav">
      <ul>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Portfolio</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
      <p>Self-studying to become a web developer. Learning HTML, CSS, and JavaScript plus jQuery through Jon Duckett's books and FreeCodeCamp. Once I get my entry level job, I wish to study more and expand on back-end development, so I can become a full-stack developer.</p>
      <p>Portfolio:</p>
      <p>Contact me here:</p>
      <input type="text" />
      <br />
      <input type="text" />
      <br />
      <input type="text" />
      <br />
      <input type="submit" value="Send" />
      <p>Here's where you can get in touch with me! Here, you can request for my resume, get more details on my experience, or learn more about my favorite hobbies! I will reply as soon as I am able, thanks!
    </div>

  </body>
</html>


body {
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: rgba(195, 246, 255, 0.56);
}

.nav {
  background-color: rgba(190, 190, 190, 0.72);
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

li {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.content {
  border: 1px solid green;
  background-color: white;
  width: 1100px;
  margin-top: 102px;
}
```

I'm trying to put a nav bar on top, with my content below it so it doesn't interfere. I set my .nav to height=100px and when I try to set my .content below it with margin-top: 102px, it ends up moving the .nav bar as well. However, when I add a border such as border: 1px solid black; to my body, it ends up working. I'm so confused! Can I make it so that without adding a border to my body, the nav displays correctly above my content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[`position: fixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)** makes the element fixed to the page, so that it will always appear in exactly that position (with content either going on top or behind if necessary). If you'd like your navbar to be positioned at the top of the page, you're looking to apply **[`top: 0`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top)** to it:

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: rgba(195, 246, 255, 0.56);
}

.nav {
  background-color: rgba(190, 190, 190, 0.72);
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

li {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.content {
  border: 1px solid green;
  background-color: white;
  width: 1100px;
  margin-top: 102px;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li>About</li>
      <li>Portfolio</li>
      <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <p>Self-studying to become a web developer. Learning HTML, CSS, and JavaScript plus jQuery through Jon Duckett's books and FreeCodeCamp. Once I get my entry level job, I wish to study more and expand on back-end development, so I can become a full-stack
      developer.</p>
    <p>Portfolio:</p>
    <p>Contact me here:</p>
    <input type="text" />
    <br />
    <input type="text" />
    <br />
    <input type="text" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
    <p>Here's where you can get in touch with me! Here, you can request for my resume, get more details on my experience, or learn more about my favorite hobbies! I will reply as soon as I am able, thanks!
  </div>

</body>
```

If you don't want it to obscure the content on scroll, you're looking for **[`position: relative`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)**. You'll also probably want to remove the `margin-top: 102px` on `.content`:

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: rgba(195, 246, 255, 0.56);
}

.nav {
  background-color: rgba(190, 190, 190, 0.72);
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

li {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.content {
  border: 1px solid green;
  background-color: white;
  width: 1100px;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li>About</li>
      <li>Portfolio</li>
      <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <p>Self-studying to become a web developer. Learning HTML, CSS, and JavaScript plus jQuery through Jon Duckett's books and FreeCodeCamp. Once I get my entry level job, I wish to study more and expand on back-end development, so I can become a full-stack
      developer.</p>
    <p>Portfolio:</p>
    <p>Contact me here:</p>
    <input type="text" />
    <br />
    <input type="text" />
    <br />
    <input type="text" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
    <p>Here's where you can get in touch with me! Here, you can request for my resume, get more details on my experience, or learn more about my favorite hobbies! I will reply as soon as I am able, thanks!
  </div>

</body>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Hey, sorry for not being more clear! I want it so that my nav bar stays as the user scrolls down, which is why I need to use position: fixed. I just don't want it to block in the beginning --

Comment: My first example still uses `position: fixed`, shifting the content up to to top of the page, into the gap, so that it doesn't initially sit on top of any other element.

Comment: Hey sorry, I didn't see both of them. New to stackoverflow, but thanks so much for the help! This did the trick! :)

Answer (score 0):

You should set `top: 0;` to your .nav class otherwise it will try to preserve the existing position vertically which could be why the margin is managing to affect it.